# Correct way of updating PHP/MySQL on a running Plesk 11.5 server?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos, plesk

I need to update my server to PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.6, currently running Plesk 11.5 (CentOS x64). I've added the following repositories to YUM:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm
```

And I can run `yum update` to globally update the system.

Should I need special commands or just merge `.rpmnew` files into existing ones (i.e. `php.ini` and `my.cnf`)?

AFAIK Plesk 11.5 does not support MySQL 5.6 officially because the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` SQL flag enable by default. Can I simply remove the flag from my.cnf until Plesk 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for experiment, I've tried to upgrade PHP and MySQL to this version.

I've only get issue with ODBC connector:

```
ODBC error #01000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so' : file not found


ODBC error #08S01: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

At installing Plesk registers following DSN in /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[MySQL]
Description             = MySQL driver for Plesk
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           =
FileUsage               = 1
Driver64                = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         =
UsageCount              = 1
```

After installing MySQL 5.6 there is no more file /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so, because it's provided by mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.5r1144-7 which is not installed any more.

But there is /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so and /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5w.so (from new 5.6 connectors).

I've replaced in /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so to /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so in /etc/odbcinst.ini.

And as I can't get how to configure socket for this driver i've add symlink:

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

After that I've see that plesk mostly runs fine even with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.

To keep link after server restart add following string in the beginning of /etc/init.d/mysqld:

```
if [ ! -L /tmp/mysql.sock ]; then  ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock ; fi
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I came to the same solution soon after starting this thread on Parallels forum (another nickname but it's just me): http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?302315-ODBC-error-08S01-unixODBC-MySQL-ODBC-5-3(w)-Driver-Can-t-connect-to-local-MySQL. Seems to work file by now, but I'd like to understand why this is happening...

Comment: It's quite clear, /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so provided by mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.5r1144-7 which is not installed any more.

Comment: Ok... but what about the missing socket /tmp/mysql.sock? I'm running another Plesk installation (mysql 5.5.36 installed from Remi, not from MySQL repository). No need to setup the symlink but it's working fine.

Comment: There is no missing /tmp/mysql.sock. mysqld on RedHat/CentOS by default stores socket at /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, it's question about default socket location compiled into /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so.   # strings /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5a.so | grep mysql.sock

Comment: sorry to bother you again. The symlink /tmp/mysql.sock is deleted every time I restart the server, right? I'm not really a linux expert.... thanks.